# Recursive Parsing Python

Tags: python, parsing, recursion

I am trying to program a calculator which allows users to input an equation and receive an answer (order of operations apply). I will not be using the input() command to gather user input, but rather the raw_input() command. I heard from another user that I could accomplish this task with the help of recursive parsing, I quote:

"The first step would be separating the string into each argument.

Let's say that the user inputs:

1+2.0+3+4

Before you can even convert to ints, you are going to need to split the string up into its components:

```
1
+
2.0
+
3
+
4
```

This will require a recursive parser..." -aong152

Additionally, I read this article which explains how recursive parsing might be used to produce the results I am looking for:

http://blog.erezsh.com/how-to-write-a-calculator-in-70-python-lines-by-writing-a-recursive-descent-parser/

I do not understand the coding that the author uses, and I have searched on this website and on Google for help in beginning to learn recursive parsing, but I cannot find anything. Can anyone give me a push in the right direction and explain the basics of recursive parsing to me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you figured out how to split the string "1+2.0+3+4" into its parts?

Comment: you would need to know about lexical analysis, grammars, abstract syntax trees. are you familiar with these? this question cannot be answered here adequately.

Comment: Sure, I can do it...

        equation_number = raw_input("\nEnter your equation now: ")
        split_equation = [equation_number[x:x+1] for x in range(0, len(equation_number), 1)]
        print split_equation

...but this is not using the recursive parsing method. I would like to learn it because it seems like a useful technique and would work perfectly for my calculator program!

Comment: [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ch7fivnW45Q) is a UCBerkeley lecture on expression parsing that should give you a basic understanding how it is done.

Comment: akonsu, I am not familiar with these... but thank you for pointing that out, now I have somewhere to start!

Answer (score 3):

Recursive parsing of simple arithmetic summations can be fairly easily analogized into adding a lot of brackets.  A recursive parser might parse the above summation like this: `1+(2.0+(3+(4)))`.  The reason for this is that you want to break the whole thing down into individual units of work that can be computed.  This means each part must contain at most two numbers and one operator (the base case for the recursion would be a single number).

Each pair of brackets is added by an additional level of recursion (the function calling itself).  So, the initial call sees something like "1 plus some complex stuff the next level of recursion will take care of for me".

When the base case is not yet reached, each call will parse the first number and the operation.  Then, it will call itself on the next part of the string after the operation, and return the results of the operator for its digit and that next call (eg. something like `return number + parse(string[length:])`).

When the base case is reached (only one number is left in the string), instead of returning something depending on another function call, it will just return the number.  Then, the recursion unwinds, with each function getting the value of the complex right hand side.  Eventually, the original call will return the result.

This is fairly easily extended to allow for other operators by having each instance of the function work on an operator (instead of an operator and a number), and the expression to the left and right of it, starting with the highest-precedence operator.  So, when parsing a string like `0+1+2*3+4`, you must start with the multiplication.  Your function, returning something like `function(left-hand-side) operator function(right-hand-side)`, would initially parse it like this: `(0+1+2)*(3+4)`.  This would turn into `(0+(1+(2)))*(3+(4))`.  You can parse linearly along operators with the same precedence, so the algorithm can iterate looking for multiplication or division to recurse on, recursing on the first one found; if none is found it can do the same for addition and subtraction, and finally if none is found just return the number as the base case (interestingly, the latter example I gave has 2 base case instances, 2 and 4; this is a feature of multiple recursion).

Comment: why must you start with multiplication when parsing `0+1+2*3+4`?

Comment: @akonsu http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Comment: @Hooked thank you :) I doubt that a recursive descent parser will be able to handle this expression if we must start with multiplication.

Comment: @akonsu "recursive descent parser" in this case refers to the decent into the nested _parenthesis_, i.e. the expression `(1+2/4)+4*2` is first recursed into `1+2/3`, this is then parsed as a single expression following order of op; recursion is stepped out to `1.5+4*2` to be parsed by order of op again. We have two problems, parsing something like `((..)(..)((..)..))..)` recursively, and then handling a single expression with no parenthesis.

Comment: @Hooked I mean the expression `0+1+2*3+4` does not have any parentheses.

Comment: It's OK for that to be the case.  The parenthesis are implied (really, I'm just throwing them in there to demonstrate the action of the parser).  The tokenizer becomes further complicated if there can be parens in the input.  Also, though the parser I described splits the string by linear scan, it is still a recursive descent parser because of the way it handles tokens.

Answer (score 1):

A fully working parser using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) that can handle +-/* can be found here:

http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py/30154950/fourFn.py

This uses a recursive grammar to handle the proper nesting of parenthesis. It may be worth working through the examples in [the book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596514235.do), you'll learn to write a grammar and how it's something different from a parser!

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing